# Do guests have tenancy rights in Florida?

Tags: tenancy

A hypothetical guest is granted one month to stay in Florida Condo.  There is no rent, deposit etc.  It is a charitable act.

Assume the guest refuses to move out at the end of the month.

- Is it a trespass issue? or is labeled something else?
- Is the guest a tenant or some other legalese /label?
- What recourse does the owner have to remove the occupants?
- Do guests have rights?  Tenancy or otherwise?
- Would the owner have the right to turn off water / electricity (utilities in owner's name)?

If the guest is not a tenant, then I suspect that *eviction* \ *unlawful detainer* does not apply?  IANAL so explaining it with minimal legal terminology is appreciated.